# can i have a subdomain pointed at one ip with a wildcard entry pointed at a different domain

Tags: domain-name-system, wildcard-subdomain

I have a domain with a wildcard subdomain entry pointed at IP-A:

```
domain-a.com   -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
*.domain-a.com -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Can I create another CNAME pointing a spcified subdomain at a different IP.  Or, rather, if I create such an entry, will it resolve to the 2nd IP?:

```
domain-a.com       -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
*.domain-a.com     -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
thing.domain-a.com -> yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
```

Will that work? Does it even make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. See [RFC 1034, section 4.3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-4.3.3) for more technical information.